# Web2Py App running on local machine but not on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, json, deployment, web2py

I have just completed making an application in Web2Py and it is working perfectly on my local machine. However, when I deploy it to PythonAnywhere and attempt to run the app, I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring since it works on my local machine. I am getting this error in almost every page of the app. Here is one function where I am getting the error:

```
def index():
    """Get parameters for current date to pass into url"""
    day = time.strftime('%d')
    month = time.strftime('%m')
    year = time.strftime('%Y')
    url = 'http://stats.nba.com/scores/#!/' + month + '/' + day + '/' + year
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36'}
    """Get results from response at NBA.com to obtain standings for Eastern and Western Conference"""
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.headers = headers
        session.get(url, headers=headers)

        params = {
            'DayOffset': '0',
            'GameDate': month + '/' + day + '/' + year,
            'LeagueID': '00'
        }

        response = session.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?DayOffset=0&LeagueID=00&gameDate='+month+'%2F'+day+'%2F'+year, params=params)
        results = response.json()
        eastHeaders = results['resultSets'][4]['headers']
        eastRows = results['resultSets'][4]['rowSet']
        westHeaders = results['resultSets'][5]['headers']
        westRows = results['resultSets'][5]['rowSet']
    return dict(eastHeaders=eastHeaders,eastRows=eastRows,westHeaders=westHeaders,westRows=westRows)
```

The specific line where I am getting the error is:

```
results = response.json()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here. For free accounts, we do not allow access to an external site unless it has an official API because people have used us to launch dos attacks/spam others before. For more details see [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/403ForbiddenError).

Also [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) is a list of the over 1000+ whitelisted sites with APIs that you can access with a free account on PythonAnywhere.

Conrad